# How to add saucy main universe package in ubuntu 12.04 lts server?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, google-closure-compiler

I want to install closure compiler on ubuntu., and dont knw how to include new packages in ubuntu.

Comment: Ask you question on  http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's in the Ubuntu repositories so you can't install it with `apt-get` or something like that. But you can get the latest version from https://github.com/google/closure-compiler (click "Download the latest version")